Clearing multiple attachments on a target with different colors in three.js
I make a WebGLTarget with several attachments. I would like to clear them with different colors. So far the only solution i found was provided by ChatGPT and it basically does it on the webgl level via gl. I know that for a long time this was a valid approach to do certain things like stencil buffer so this kinda makes sense, but if there is a built in solution i would prefer that.
Alternatively, if i draw a full screen quad with different outputs, how much slower is this than clearing the buffer?
